# Wix binaries in TFS preview

Tags: wix, tfsbuild

I want to add WIX binaries in TFS preview website how to do that
I have vs 2012 along with build on tfs 2012 in windows server 2012

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems WiX is now preinstalled on the hosted TFS build servers.  However, ICE validation still fails due to environmental constraints.

If you use Votive to create your .SLN/.WIXPROJ/.WXS and go into project properties and disable validation, it should build without doing anything else.

That said, disabling validation is a non-starter for me.  Therefore, I'd suggest setting up your own build server and installing WiX 3.7 on it.

Comment: Yes that seems to work really setting up own build server i just did that now yeah no more editing msbuild and all that is some kind of quick fix solution for that still will try  to use msbuild if i get time to do r&d anyways Thanks so much for Help really appreciated

Answer (score 4):

Here are the specific steps to achieve what you are looking for.

1. [Integrate the WiX toolset into your source control](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/daily_builds.htm) - that link gives you the steps to use the binaries.zip file to get the tools and check them into your build system.
2. [Suppress ICE validation in your .wixproj](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/msbuild_task_reference_light.htm) - the TFS build servers do not allow validation to work so set the SuppressValidation Property in MSBuild to true.

   ```
   <PropertyGroup>
     <SuppressValidation>true</SuppressValidation>
   </PropertyGroup>
   ```
3. Manually run validation - validation is like static analysis, it will find problems before you ship to your customers. So, after each build, use `smoke.exe` to run validation on your MSI on a local server:

   ```
   smoke.exe path\to\your.msi
   ```

Comment: My tests indicate #1 is not needed anymore.  For #3, I really like to fail my builds when unit tests fail. I'd be concerned that people forget to run smoke.

Comment: #1 is not needed *if* TFS Preview pre-installs the version of the WiX toolset you want. Safer to check-in. #3 is a limitiation of the TFS Preview today and this is the best work around at the moment. I have ideas to address this.

Comment: Hi rob, it means that there is no way how to run smoke in CI? I mean when the build service do not have admin rights?

Comment: AFAIK, yes, today. Radical changes required to workaround the MSI limitation that could maybe be done in WiX v4.x.

Comment: You lose all the elegance and simplicity if you go the route of checking it all in.  Setting up your own build server is easy and the reliable way of truly controlling the build environment.  Plus you can send your build drops to a local network share instead of doing the silly upload to server and download as a zip which is very painful.